# $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+\frac{1}{|f(x)|})=0$. Find $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, absolute-value

Let a function $f$ be defined in a hollow neighborhood of $a\in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose :
 $$\lim_{x\to a}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{|f(x)|}\right)=0$$

Find $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ and prove that this is the limit by definition.

**My approach**:
It is easy to see that if this limit exists it should be $-1$ but I can't prove it by definition. Please help.

Comment: How did you get -1?

Comment: sory my mistake I replaced "+" by a "-" in the question

Comment: Have a look at the function $g(x)=x+\frac{1}{\vert x \vert}$ and see what $g(x)\approx 0$ implies about $x$. This should help you pin down where $f(x)$ needs to be for your limit to hold.

Comment: Are you expected to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit to show this?

Comment: yes or by heine's defenition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+\frac{1}{|f(x)|})=0$, then for $x$ close enough to $a$, $f(x)+\frac{1}{|f(x)|}<1$. A quick look at the graph of $x+\frac{1}{|x|}$ shows that this means $f(x)$ is negative, so you actually have that $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-\frac{1}{f(x)})=0$.

Some algebra shows that $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-\frac{1}{f(x)})^2+4=\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)})^2=4$, and thus that $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)})=\pm2$. Noting that $f$ is negative as $x\to a$, we can take the negative root, thus seeing that:

$$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-\frac{1}{f(x)})=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)})=-2$$

and thus, finally,that $f(x)\to -1$ as $x \to a$.

Note: One can use the fact that $g(x)=x+\frac{1}{|x|}$ has a continuous inverse around $0$ directly, though this arguably presupposes extra knowledge about inverse functions. In any case, if  you're comfortable using it, it provides a slightly quicker route to the answer.

Comment: i am expected to show that by epsilon delta or heine.

Comment: @Lior If you know that $f<0$ and $-\epsilon<f-\frac{1}{f}<\epsilon$, you can show that $1-\sqrt{1+\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<1+f<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, this gives you guarantees that $f+1$ will be close to 0. There's some algebraic tidying-up to be done, but the core ideas are there.

Comment: Are you using that $f(x)<0$ for x near a to conclude that $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)})$ exists?

Comment: @user84413 Yep - limits are a local concept, and locally to $x\approx a$, $\vert f(x) \vert = -f(x)$.

Comment: I'm satisfied with the answer above, I was told that we are not obliged to use the formal definition of limit.